# Performance increase in function to find base of a number where it's a palindrome

Tags: python, performance, palindrome

I'm trying to solve for the smallest base of a number where its a palindrome. So for 999 return 10 for base 10 and for 0 return 2 for base 2. The following is the solution. Here is my question, how can I avoid using the `if` statement to check for base 10. Is there something strange that happens to a binary number when its in base ten that prevents the `is_palindrome` function from working properly. I've been staring at it and need some fresh eyes or a new approach. Everything works but I just feel like its inefficient or can be improved ( big-O memory or processing)

```
def answer(n):
    if (n < 0 or n > 1000):
        raise Exception("Parameter out of bounds")

    b_number = int(str(bin(n))[2:])
    base = 1
    palindrome = False
    while not palindrome:
        base += 1
        if base == 10:
            if is_palindrome(n, base):
                palindrome = True
        elif is_palindrome(b_number, int(str(bin(base))[2:])):
            palindrome = True
    return base


def is_palindrome(number, base):
    forward = number
    rev = 0
    while number > 0:
        digit = math.floor(number % base)
        rev = rev * base + digit
        number = math.floor(number / base)
    return (forward == rev)
```

Comment: That's some mighty odd logic there in `answer()`. And it doesn't work. Try e.g. `answer(12)`. Note that `12 = 2*5 + 2*1`, so `12` is a palindrome in base `5`. If you just call `is_palindrome(n,base)` for all bases however …

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, smh embarrassing :) but i got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For an ugly-but-short solution, try abusing string-int casting & indexing:

```
def is_palindrome(num):
    s = str(num)
    return s[::-1] == s

def change_base(num, base):
    return int(str(num), base=base)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix is to stop trying to solve in binary! as indicated by the comment above. I left in code that I used for an earlier solution. Since it worked for my limited test cases I ignored it, final solution.

```
def answer(n):
    if (n < 0 or n > 1000):
        raise Exception("Parameter out of bounds")
    base = 1
    palindrome = False
    while not palindrome:
        base += 1
        if is_palindrome(n, base):
                palindrome = True
    return base
```